# _imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so is built for a different architecture (x86_64) than the one that your machine is running (arm64) and thus cannot be used

Tags: python, numpy, x86-64, arm64

Hi I am trying to run some scripts for face recognition this is the code for one of them

```
import face_recognition
image = face_recognition.load_image_file('./img/groups/team2.jpg')
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

# Array of coords of each face
# print(face_locations)

print(f'There are {len(face_locations)} people in this image')
```

When I run the code, the terminal says that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kpop/Desktop/face_recognition_examples-master/findfaces.py", line 1, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "/Users/kpop/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/face_recognition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "/Users/kpop/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    import PIL.Image
  File "/Users/kpop/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kpop/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/kpop/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

Does it mean that the Python script is built for a different architecture (x86_64) than the one that my machine is running (arm64)? and if so is there anyway I can solve this issue?

Just to clarify I am using MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020), MacOs Monterey.

Comment: It means that the file it is talking about (`_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so`), which is a part of the `PIL` library, is not the right architecture.

Comment: Also, this same error with this same library has been posted about before - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289889/how-do-i-fix-the-mach-o-but-wrong-architecture-error-in-pycharm), for example - so can you clarify why that didn't help?

Comment: @RandomDavis thnx I didn't know about that, I will try and consult that page and see if there's an asnwer to my question

Comment: I don't know how you coudn't have found that if you didn't google the error or do some kind of basic research first. This site is not a substitute for the basic research and critical thinking you need to do as a programmer. It should be a last resort, not the first place you go when you get stuck. Just keep that in mind for the future. Most of the time, what you need is already out there.